# Is there a way to serialize and deserialize a pointer in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, pointers

Is it possible to serialize or deserialize any pointer? Suppose I have a class as follows

```
  public unsafe class Class001
  {
        public byte* pointer;

        public Class001()
        {

            var byteArr = new byte[] {12, 54, 20};

            fixed(byte* ptr = byteArr)
            {
                pointer = ptr;
            }
         }
   }
```

Can I store the hex value of *pointer* in a file and reconstruct it using Reflection by reading the file?

I used the word serialization/deserialization just to denote saving some values in a file and reconstruct it later, it need not to be any standard serialization process.

Comment: You realise as soon as you leave the fixed block, the value of pointer is no longer guaranteed to point to the start of the array anyway?

Comment: By "serialize ... pointer", do you mean "the value *of* the pointer", or "the value of the data *at* pointer" ?

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I was talking about value of the pointer. Anyway as Jon Grant & MattDavey said, its irrelevant to deserialize a pointer.

Comment: What you **can** serialize/deserialize is a memory offset, ie the address of bye[] + 0x10, using a new fixed block and obtaining a pointer to the array, adding the deserialized offset value...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely not! A pointer is a reference to a particular memory location. You may indeed serialize the hex value of that particular memory address - but when you deserialize it, that memory address will certainly contain something entirely different.

Comment: ...or, even more likely, it will point to an invalid (unallocated) address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also thought so, just wanted to confirm.